# array market need a guide or an answer

Tags: java, arrays, swing, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class market4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("---MENU---");
        String[] menu = {"[1]item list","[2]sales","[3]print","[4]exit"};
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            System.out.println(menu[i]);
        }

        int MenuList;
        String  MenuString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Choose number: ");
        MenuList = Integer.parseInt(MenuString);

        if(MenuList==1) {
            System.out.println();
            String[] list = {"hotdog","donut","eggpie","pizza","lasagna"};
            int[] cost = {5,15,25,35,45};
            int[] selling = {10,20,30,40,50};
            int[] qty ={5,5,5,5,5};
            System.out.println("item"+"\tcost"+"\tSelling"+"\tinv qty");
            for (int m=0; m<list.length;m++) {
                System.out.println(list[m]+"\t"+cost[m]+"\t\t"+selling[m]+"\t\t"+qty[m]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Select an Item", "Welcome " +  "!",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, list, "Hotdog");

                String[] itemQuantity = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
                String itemq = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                    "Enter   Quantity", "Welcome",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, itemQuantity, "1");
            }

        } else if(MenuList==2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sales");
        } else if(MenuList==3) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"print");
        } else if(MenuList==4) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exit,Bye");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

I just made my first array program. I don't know how I get my inputs here:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sales");
```

Also in the printing section I need the program to make a print for the items I bought:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"print");
```

i am asking for menu to be loop. menulist==1 to be printed in menulist==2. thats all :) < done already

Comment: What exactly is the problem. Compile Error, Exception, logical problem,...

Comment: nothing i just dont know how to get the inputs i made so that i can see the items and price of it

Comment: Are you saying you want the String[] list options in the JOption Pane?  Or that you want to display the items, names, prices e.t.c

Comment: yeah sort of i want the items i bought in if(menuList==1) to be shown in menuList==2.

Comment: You mean the items in the arrays?

Comment: yes. i want it to be inputted in menulist==2 , i dont need to use joption i just need to print it in jcreator.

Comment: Please take care to keep your code formatted cleanly.  It makes it easier for others to read.

Comment: sorry first time posting

Comment: already done and this is my first post sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you originally wanted.  You will use option 1 first to make an 'Order'.  Then you are looped back to the menu, which allows you to use options 2 and 3 to view the menu.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class market4 {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int MenuList; //Declared outside the loop, this will keep the variable in memory as we go through the program. 
    String myOrder = "No order currently set"; //Declared outside the loop for above reasons.  This will become the order.
do{  //Start of Do Loop, this will keep you going through the menu. 

    System.out.println("---MENU---");
    String[] menu = {"[1]item list","[2]sales","[3]print","[4]exit"};
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
        System.out.println(menu[i]);
    }


    String MenuString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Choose number: ");
    MenuList = Integer.parseInt(MenuString);


    if(MenuList==1) {
        System.out.println();
        String[] list = {"hotdog","donut","eggpie","pizza","lasagna"};
        int[] cost = {5,15,25,35,45};
        int[] selling = {10,20,30,40,50};
        int[] qty ={5,5,5,5,5};
        System.out.println("item"+"\tcost"+"\tSelling"+"\tinv qty");
        for (int m=0; m<list.length;m++) {
            System.out.println(list[m]+"\t"+cost[m]+"\t\t"+selling[m]+"\t\t"+qty[m]);
        }

        myOrder = "";
        ArrayList<String> Orders = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Select an Item", "Welcome " +  "!",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, list, "Hotdog");



            String[] itemQuantity = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
            String itemq = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter   Quantity", "Welcome",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, itemQuantity, "1");

            Orders.add("Item " + input + "  Quantity " + itemq);
        }

        for(String s : Orders){
            myOrder += "\n" + s; 
        }
     } else if(MenuList==2) {            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sales \n" + myOrder);   
    } else if(MenuList==3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"print");
        System.out.println(myOrder);
    } else if(MenuList==4) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exit,Bye");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Invalid");
    }
            }while(MenuList != 4); //End of Do loop.  Exiting program when selecting exit (Number 4)
}
}
```

Comment: uhm, using array.list how do i use it so that i can make the items i choose in if(menulist==1) to if(menulist==2) by displaying it not using joptionpane.

Comment: You mean you want the items you select in MenuList==1 to be available in MenuList==2?

Comment: yes thats what im aiming for

Comment: Is my modified answer more what you are after?

Comment: im kinda lost on how to get the value that i inputted in MenuList==1 to Menulist==2..do i need to loop the if else statement? so i can get back to menulist==2 so i can view the things i choose or just use if statement?

Comment: sorry for my bad english and my codes, its like this in MenuList==1 i choose an item and input a quantity the item should be printed with its price * quantity in MenuList==2 , so should i also loop the if else statement?

Comment: I have 'rejigged' my answer based on your latest comments,  if it's still not quite right please comment again and i'll give it another go

Comment: wow thnx i was just about to say if i can use do while ..